# How can I move a sprite while simultaneously firing a projectile in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to write some logic using Swift 4 and SpriteKit to allow the user to  move the spaceship around using a drag action while also allowing them to shoot a projectile. I can drag the spaceship around with my left thumb, but once I begin shooting with my right thumb by tapping, the spaceship stops moving.

I have enabled 'enableMultiTouch' in the viewDidLoad(). I feel as though I am very close to having this working, I am just missing a piece to allow a user to do both at the same time. Thanks in advance.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)

    if player.contains(touchLocation) {
      playerIsTouched = true
    } else {
      // 2 - Set up initial location of projectile
      let projectile = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "projectile")
      projectile.position = player.position

      projectile.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: projectile.size.width/2)
      projectile.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
      projectile.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.projectile
      projectile.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.monster
      projectile.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.none
      projectile.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

      // 3 - Determine offset of location to projectile
      let offset = touchLocation - projectile.position

      // 4 - Bail out if you are shooting down or backwards
      if offset.x < 0 {
        return
      } else {
        run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("laser-shot-basic.wav", waitForCompletion: false))
        shotsFired += 1
        accuracyLabel.text = "\(trunc((shotsHit/shotsFired*100) * 10)/10)% Accuracy"
      }

      // 5 - OK to add now - you've double checked position
      addChild(projectile)

      // 6 - Get the direction of where to shoot
      let direction = offset.normalized()

      // 7 - Make it shoot far enough to be guaranteed off screen
      let shootAmount = direction * 1000

      // 8 - Add the shoot amount to the current position
      let realDest = shootAmount + projectile.position

      // 9 - Create the actions
      let actionMove = SKAction.move(to: realDest, duration: 2.0)
      let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
      projectile.run(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]))
    }

    if pauseButton.contains(touchLocation) {

      run(gameLostSound, completion: {
        let scene = LevelSelectScene(size: self.size)
        self.view?.presentScene(scene)
      })


    }
//    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
//      let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
//      let previousPointOfTouch = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
//
//      let amountDragged = pointOfTouch.x - previousPointOfTouch.x
//
//      player.position.x += amountDragged
//    }

  }

  override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if (playerIsTouched == true) {
      player.position = (touches.first?.location(in: self))!
    }
  }

  override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // 1 - Choose one of the touches to work with
    guard let touch = touches.first else {
      return
    }
    let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)


    if playerIsTouched {
      playerIsTouched = false
    }

  }
```

Comment: That's not exactly how you use buttons in Sprite Kit.  If you are going to use multiple touch buttons, create SKNode objects and give them names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you tap-to-fire that will cause two events: a 'begins' and an 'ends' event. However your **touchesEnded** method does not distinguish *which* touch has just ended, and sets your **playerIsTouched** parameter to false, thus further movement ceases.

There are multiple ways of fixing this, depending on the larger and future structure of the app, but one way would be: in **touchesEnded**, use the location of the touch to determine whether it is the drag touch that has ended and only reset **playerIsTouched** if that is the case.